# How can I write in a cell that is X number of column away from the cell I am on (X is a value defined in another cell)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a set of items which are classified as `A/B/C`. For example:

Item & category :

[image]

I want to make A/B/C as columns but place each items spanning across. For example:

Each item as columns :

[image]

How can I do this when there can be any number of items under each category?

I think this is possible with macros, but I am hoping to steer clear from macros as much as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the code and try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TEST()

    Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long, LastColumn2 As Long, i As Long, y As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        arr = Array("A", "B", "C") '<- Create an array with the desirable Items

        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) '<- Loop array
            'Find Last column of row 12 in order to import Titles
            LastColumn = .Cells(12, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            If LastColumn = 1 And .Cells(11, LastColumn).Value = "" Then
                .Cells(11, LastColumn).Value = arr(i)
            Else
                .Cells(11, LastColumn + 1).Value = arr(i)
            End If
            'Find Last row of column B in order to create the loop range
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            'Loop column B from 1 to last row of column B
            For y = 1 To LastRow
                'Check if looping value is the same with array value
                If .Range("B" & y).Value = arr(i) Then
                    'Find Last column of row 12 in order to import values
                    LastColumn2 = .Cells(12, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

                    If LastColumn2 = 1 And .Cells(12, LastColumn2).Value = "" Then
                        .Cells(12, 1).Value = .Range("A" & y).Value
                    Else
                        .Cells(12, LastColumn2 + 1).Value = .Range("A" & y).Value
                    End If

                End If

            Next y

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

**Results:**

[image]